# SQLite.Interop.dll error when publishing application

Tags: c#, winforms, sqlite, publish

I am trying to publish a WinForms c# application, but whenever I do, regardless of x86 or x64, I get an error on the target machine, saying that the .dll is missing. I have tried various solutions, but nothing seems to work, from adding the files manually, to switching the output to either x86 or x64, nothing works; the file doesn't get created if I publish it.

The only thing that actually works, is if I copy the whole of the release/debug folder on the target machine. That, however, is undesirable, as I don't want the user to actually have/see all those files. How do I solve the error?

Comment: You basically want to create a setup file rather than giving the debug is it?

Comment: Correct. The application will only run on a couple of computers, but I'd rather it have a clean install, than to always copy and paste the debug/release folder w/ the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To create a new setup project**

- On the File menu, point to Add, then click New Project.
- In the resulting Add New Project dialog box, in the Project Types pane, open the Other Project Types node, open Setup and Deployment Projects, and select Visual Studio Installer.
- In the Templates pane, choose Setup Project for a standard setup, or Web Setup Project for a Web application.

**To add an existing setup project to a solution**

- On the File menu, point to Add, then click Existing Project.
- In the resulting Add Existing Project dialog box, browse to the location of the setup project and click Open.

Comment: I am using VS2017, I can not find any of the options you described.

Comment: @EInherjar you will have to install setup and deployment projects on to your PC as it's not included in the visual studio package. Once that is done you should be able to find the options.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I actually fixed the problem by adding the file directly by adding an existing item and it worked, it is included in the project and it gives me no problems.